# Tranform Dataframe of lists to long format

Tags: r, list

**Problem:**

I have a tibble/dataframe that looks something like this:

```
x <- c("Item A", "Item B", "Item C")
y <- c("Item D", "Item E", "Item F")
z <- c("Item G", "Item H")
my_list <- list(x, y, z)

Name<-c("Name 1","Name 2", "Name 3")

Df<-as_tibble(cbind(Name,I(my_list)))
```

I would like to transform the tibble into a long format as seen below.

```
| Rnum  |  Name     |  Item     |
|:----: |:------:   |:------:   |
|   1   | Name 1    | Item A    |
|   1   | Name 1    | Item B    |
|   1   | Name 1    | Item C    |
|   2   | Name 2    | Item D    |
|   2   | Name 2    | Item E    |
|   2   | Name 2    | Item F    |
|   3   | Name 3    | Item G    |
|   3   | Name 3    | Item H    |
```

I have tried everything I could think of and could not figure it out. I would appreciate any help with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use `unnest` to bring the list into separate rows in the dataframe.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

Df %>%
  unnest(c(Name, V2)) %>%
  mutate(Rnum = match(Name, unique(Name)), .before = 1)

#   Rnum Name   V2    
#  <int> <chr>  <chr> 
#1     1 Name 1 Item A
#2     1 Name 1 Item B
#3     1 Name 1 Item C
#4     2 Name 2 Item D
#5     2 Name 2 Item E
#6     2 Name 2 Item F
#7     3 Name 3 Item G
#8     3 Name 3 Item H
```

Answer (score 0):

We could use

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
Df %>% 
    mutate(Rnum = row_number()) %>% 
    unnest(my_list)
# A tibble: 8 x 3
  Name   my_list  Rnum
  <chr>  <chr>   <int>
1 Name 1 Item A      1
2 Name 1 Item B      1
3 Name 1 Item C      1
4 Name 2 Item D      2
5 Name 2 Item E      2
6 Name 2 Item F      2
7 Name 3 Item G      3
8 Name 3 Item H      3
```